# How can I define an INI file grammar using the BNFC?

Tags: parsing, haskell, bnf, context-free-grammar, ebnf

http://www.cs.chalmers.se/Cs/Research/Language-technology/BNFC/

how should I write my labeled BNF to get BNFC to generate a INI parser for me?

I have only gotten so far o__O!

```
entrypoints File ;

comment "#" ;

token ID ( letter | digit | ["-_'"] )+ ;

Ini. File ::= [Section] ;
Sect. Section ::= "[" ID "]" [Statement] ;
Bind. Statement ::= ID "=" ID ;

separator Statement "\n" ;
terminator Section "" ;
```

---

```
[name]
#x = 10
y = 20
```

---

```
Parse Successful!

[Abstract Syntax]

Ini [Sect (ID "name") [Bind (ID "y") (ID "20")]]

[Linearized tree]

[name]y = 20
```

---

```
[name]
x = 10
#y = 20
```

---

```
Parse Successful!

[Abstract Syntax]

Ini [Sect (ID "name") [Bind (ID "x") (ID "10")]]

[Linearized tree]

[name]x = 10
```

o__O I'm stuck ...

Comment: What do you want to do next?  Seems like this pretty much fulfills the needs for parsing ini files

Comment: not really because with the above grammar sections can only have a single binding. I'd like to be able to parse all sorts of ini files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked one of the BNFC devs and quote his reply here:

> Space characters such as newlines are
>   not well supported in tokens, because
>   BNFC has a hard-wired lexer type
>   "space". The idea is that spaces can't
>   carry meaning in "well-behaved"
>   languages. One of those restrictions
>   that has made BNFC so simple... but
>   you should be able solve this by using
>   a preprocessor, e.g. parse input line
>   by line.

---

Like for example:

```
entrypoints File ;

comment "#" ;

token ID ( letter | digit | ["-_'"] )+ ;

Ini. File ::= [Section] ;
Sect. Section ::= "[" ID "]" [Statement] ;
Bind. Statement ::= ID "=" ID ;

separator Statement "//" ;
terminator Section "//" ;
```

---

Read:

```
[name]
x = 10
y = 20
```

---

Preprocess:

```
[name]//
x = 10//
y = 20//
```

---

Parse:

```
Ini [Sect (ID "name") [Bind (ID "x") (ID "10"), Bind (ID "y") (ID "20")]]
```

---

Transform:

```
                                          ↓                       ↓
Ini [Sect (ID "name") [Bind (ID "x") (ID "0"), Bind (ID "y") (ID "0")]]
```

---

Write:

```
[name]//
x = 0//
y = 0//
```

---

Postprocess:

```
[name]
x = 0
y = 0
```

(not checked, don't know if it works, just to give an idea!!)